# How does Coconut Battery determine a Macbook battery's design capacity?

Tags: battery

A macbook's battery has three charge numbers:

1. The current charge
2. The maximum charge
3. The design capacity

Even if a Macbook remains plugged in, OS X does not attempt to charge—as long as (1) is 95% of (2), which is why the percentage in the notification bar will often be between 95% and 100%.

These two numbers are in contrast with a battery's "design capacity".
[Coconut Battery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) is the only software I've found that reports a Macbook battery's "design capacity".

This design capacity does not appear in Apple's specs, in System Information, or at everymac.com.

How does Coconut Battery determine the design capacity of a battery?

Comment: iStat Menus also displays battery design capacity

Comment: And here I thought a Coconut Battery was something like a [lemon cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery).  How disappointing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can find this information along with much other battery and/or system information from the command

```
ioreg
```

This command, according to its man page, does:

> ioreg displays the I/O Kit registry.  It shows the heirarchical<sup>1</sup> registry
>        structure as an inverted tree.

<sub>*<sup>1</sup>: heirarchical [sic]*</sub>

Using a filter by class name (`AppleSmartBattery` for battery) to get only battery-related information:

```
$ ioreg -brc AppleSmartBattery
```

> ```
> -b    Show the object name in bold.
> -r    Show subtrees rooted by objects that match the specified criteria.
>        If none of -c, -k, or -n are supplied, -r has no effect.
> -c    Show the object properties only if the object is an instance of, or
>        derives from, the specified C++ class (e.g. IOService).
> ```
>
> From `man ioreg`.

Will print something like this:

```
$ ioreg -brc AppleSmartBattery
+-o AppleSmartBattery  <class AppleSmartBattery, id 0x100000254, registered, ma$
{
  "ExternalConnected" = Yes
  "TimeRemaining" = 0
  "InstantTimeToEmpty" = 65535
  "ExternalChargeCapable" = Yes
  "FullPathUpdated" = 1464849055
  "CellVoltage" = (4298,4292,4299,0)
  "Voltage" = 12889
  "BatteryInvalidWakeSeconds" = 30
  "AdapterInfo" = 0
  "MaxCapacity" = 5524
  "PermanentFailureStatus" = 0
  "Manufacturer" = "SMP"
  "Location" = 0
  "CurrentCapacity" = 5524
  "LegacyBatteryInfo" = {"Amperage"=0,"Flags"=5,"Capacity"=5524,"Current"=5$
  "FirmwareSerialNumber" = 1
  "BatteryInstalled" = Yes
  "PackReserve" = 200
  "CycleCount" = 318
  "DesignCapacity" = 6330
  "OperationStatus" = 58371
  "ManufactureDate" = 17726
  "AvgTimeToFull" = 65535
  "BatterySerialNumber" = "D864403T3UVFVN7A6"
  "BootPathUpdated" = 1464353527
  "PostDischargeWaitSeconds" = 120
  "Temperature" = 3096
  "UserVisiblePathUpdated" = 1464849490
  "InstantAmperage" = 0
  "ManufacturerData" = <000000000702000a03890000034a34340330304103534449032$
  "MaxErr" = 1
  "FullyCharged" = Yes
  "DeviceName" = "bq20z451"
  "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  "Amperage" = 0
  "IsCharging" = No
  "DesignCycleCount9C" = 1000
  "PostChargeWaitSeconds" = 120
  "AvgTimeToEmpty" = 65535
}
```

The field you are looking for is `DesignCapacity`. For convenience, filter it out with `grep` (unit is milliamp-hours, or mAh):

```
$ ioreg -brc AppleSmartBattery | grep DesignCapacity
      "DesignCapacity" = 6330
```

*Your `DesignCapacity` field may not display `6330` as its value. I'm using a 13" mid-2014 rMBP, but you may be using another system with different battery ratings.*

Apart from battery information, `ioreg` can be used to find out more about your system and other peripherals - somewhat like a command-line System Information tool.

---

If you're looking for a code-implementation of this command, take a look at [Beltex's SystemKit over on Github](https://github.com/beltex/SystemKit). It's one of the coolest Swift libraries I know of.

*Disclaimer: not affiliated to SystemKit or Beltex. Just a happy user of SystemKit.*