# Is it possible to view the CPU/GPU temperatures **from the command line**?

Tags: battery, gpu, cpu, temperature

When this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/54329/7985) was asked in 2012, specifically mentioning the "command line" requirement, an [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54332/7985) suggested [Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/LegacyProducts.html) (a "legacy" product). Running all three, Temperature Monitor along with [smcFanControl](https://www.eidac.de/) and [iStat Menu](https://istat-nano.en.softonic.com/mac), side-by-side shows the problem. I don't want this level of perpetual distraction.

[image: menu bar temperature monitors]

**I suspect the following answer: It is not possible to see the CPU&GPU temperatures from the command line.** I suspect this because both iStat and `Temperature Monitor` install additional drivers. If that's the case, it would be nice to record that answer.

[smcFanControl](https://www.eidac.de/) and [iStat Menu](https://istat-nano.en.softonic.com/mac) are nice utilities to make you keep an eye on the temperature of your CPU. The former shows only the CPU temperature, and both are too distracting (the latter's precursor, iStat Nano, could sit silently in the Dashboard until one needed it, plus iStat Menu seems rather sticky: I haven't figured out how to delete it yet—just removing the program from `/Applications` is insufficient.)

It was nice to find that [ioreg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240407/7985)
will reveal the Maximum Capacity of a battery (in contrast to the static Design Capacity, the Maximum Capacity signals the health of the battery). Using a program (such as [CoconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/)) is not necessary.

A [script](https://gist.github.com/earlonrails/9374070) (still using ioreg) will reveal the battery temperature

> AppleSmartBattery Temperature: 
>   30 °C
>   62.0 °F

and so I'm hoping for a renewed answer in 2017 to the following question.

How can I view the CPU temperature from the command line? It would especially be nice to also see the GPU temperature. OS X just crashed and rebooted on its own, and the Console logs ("Event: GPU Reset" and "GPU HangState 0x00000000") suggest that the GPU might be the culprit. I'm trying to determine if it's time to reapply the thermal paste and reattach the heatsinks (never done this before; not even sure it's within my ability).

Comment: iStat Menu (or iStat Menus) is a different app than iStat Nano

Comment: There are several answers to the question you've linked to, some of them mentioning command line tools. Can you try these first as well? And, if necessary, come back and indicate in the question text why none of them matches your needs?

Comment: not a duplicate. GPU temps would be different than CPU temps, assuming there's different sensors to tap into.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a suitable solution might be in one of the less-voted answers on the question you linked:

> This open source command line utility worked for me:
>   https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp.
>
> M. Lavoie is using code Apple released a while back: Apple System
>   Management Control (SMC) Tool Copyright (C) 2006 but it works fine on
>   my 2011 Mini.

If smcFanControl is functional for you, but you dislike the display format, then perhaps this little C program is a better fit for your use case.

Comment: You're right. As is clear from my question, I had looked carefully at the four other answers, but missed this one-liner. It does half the job—no GPU temp. I'll accept this answer if no one suggests a fuller solution, or else delete the question if it continues to be downvoted as duplicate.